# I need to create a folder with a batch file, but it has to be named automatically

Tags: batch-file

I'm making this batch file for a program i'm making but the program needs to create a folder.  How can i do this?
the folder needs to automatically name itself after the current user.
Thanks!

\BAT\EPHR\Recoverd\%USERNAME%\

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir \BAT\EPHR\Recoverd\%USERNAME%`